# C++ Counting Specific Counters in Character Array from File

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to count the number of specific characters from a file. The problem I have run into is that the output is a huge number that does not match up with the amount of each letter in the file.

RainOrShine.txt

RRCSSSCSCRRRCSSSCSSRSCCRCRRCSS

SSSCCSSSCCSSSCCSSSCRCRCCSSSSSS

SSSSCSSSCSSSCRRCCCSSSSSCSSSSCS

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string filelocation = "C:/Users/erizj/OneDrive/Documents/RainOrShine.txt";
ifstream textfile;
textfile.open(filelocation.c_str());

char weather[3][30];
int countR,countC,countS = 0;



if (!textfile)
{
    cout << "Error opening the file.";
    return 0;
}

else
{ // Read weather data in from file
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 30; col++)
        {
            textfile >> weather[row][col];

            if(weather[row][col]=='R'){
                countR++;
            }
            if(weather[row][col]=='C'){
                countC++;
            }
            if(weather[row][col]=='S'){
                countS++;
            }
        }
    }

}

cout<<"Rainy Days during 3-Month Period: "<<countR<<endl;
cout<<"Cloudy Days during 3-Month Period: "<<countC<<endl;
cout<<"Sunny Days during 3-Month Period: "<<countS<<endl;
//cout<<"Rainy Days in June: "<<

textfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Output:

Rainy Days during 3-Month Period: 4201688

Cloudy Days during 3-Month Period: 6356911

Sunny Days during 3-Month Period: 50

Does it have something to do with the counter that I set up? Thank in advance.

Comment: Unless this is some sort of school exercise [usage of std::map](http://ideone.com/4Ez8X7) is much shorter and less error prone.

Comment: Beside the point: you only need one `char`, not ninety, since you never use the array for anything except looking at the last value you read.

Comment: I would believe that `std::map` is overkill.  One could store the data in `std::vector` since days are contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

```
int countR,countC,countS = 0;
```

initializes `countS` but leaves `countR` and `countC` uninitialized.

Comment: In addition to aschelpers keen find, your current code will have additional problems if a month has 31 days.  Otherwise it may be easier to just load the text file into a buffer and use std::count for 'R', 'C' and 'S'.  If your file contains multiple months after 3, build an index of the string based on CR & LF (I would split the string personally, then use std::count on each string).

Answer (score 0):

Your program is assuming that there are a fixed number of rows and columns in the data.  This could be a problem.

I suggest a more flexible approach, no assumptions about how the data is organized or the quantity of data.

Let's define a structure for our database.  The data can be stored sequentially, but we need the data structure to be dynamic:  `std::vector`.

Now to read in the data before making any analysis:

```
std::vector<char> database;
std::string text_line; // Easier to read in a lot of data
while (getline(data_file, text_line))
{
  std::string::size_type index;
  const std::string::size_type  length = text_line.length();
  for (index = 0; index < length; ++index)
  {
      const char c = text_line[index];
      if ((c == 'R') || (c == 'S') || (c == 'C'))
      {
         database.push_back(c);
      }
  }
}
```

Since the data is read into a database, you can analyze it:

```
unsigned int duration = 0;
unsigned int rain_quantity = 0;
unsigned int sunny_quantity = 0;
unsigned int cloudy_quantity = 0;
// Set up the duration for the first 30 days
duration = 30;
if (database.size() < 30)
{
  duration = database.size();
}
for (unsigned int index = 0; index < duration; ++index)
{
  const char c = database[index];
  if (c == 'C')
  {
    ++cloudy_quantity;
  }
  else
  {
    if (c == 'R')
    {
       ++rain_quantity;
    }
    else
    {
       ++sunny_quantity;
    }
  }
}
```

You can perform other analysis without reading the data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize all of your integer variables separately.
`int countR = 0, countS = 0, countT = 0;`